# After setting new ulimit it comes back to 0

Tags: linux, redhat

A client of ours running Red Hat is setting ulimit to unlimited in /etc/profile to:
ulimit -c unlimited
But after a while it goes back to
ulimit -S -c 0

Therefore he cannot generate a core dump that's needed for a Debug.

Anyone have any idea why does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

I think they are resetted to defaults by pam's pam_limits.so when opening new sessions. 
Ask your customer to edit */etc/security/limits.conf* or to add a specific conf file in */etc/security/limits.d/*

Format is (it's well documented in limits.conf):

```
#<domain>  <type>  <item>  <value>
```

ie:

```
*          soft    core    unlimited
```

Or you could remove

```
session     required      pam_limits.so
```

from */etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac*, but it could have nasty collateral effects.